# Conditional form depending on answers in select list not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm building a simple form where input fields are enabled depending on a choice a user makes in a select list. I'm using a little javascript for this.
I get it to work for one condition but there are 2 conditions within the form.

**First** is a select drop down where depending on one of the two answers 2 input fields appear. 
The **second** is an input field that appears depending on one option chosen in a select list (namely "other")

here is the html:

```
<div class="form-div1">
<label>Select your profile</label>
<br>
<select>
    <option value="option1">I'm a first-time user</option>
    <option value="option2">I would like to renew or upgrade</option>
</select>
```

**Sorry** but my html code is normally longer but it keeps getting cut off by the editor. I assume it's because it encountered a closing div? You can see the full code in the jsfiddle

here is the js:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('.form-div2').show();
    $('.form-div3').show();
    $('.form-div4').show();
    $('.form-div42').hide();
    $('.form-div5').show();

    $('#select').change(function () {
        if ($('#select option:selected').text() == "I'm a first-time user") {
            $('.form-div2').show();
            $('.form-div3').show();
        } else if ($('#select option:selected').text() == "I would like to renew or upgrade") {
            $('.form-div2').hide();
            $('.form-div3').hide();
        }
    });

    $('#select').change(function () {
        if ($('#select option:selected').text() == "Other") {
            $('.form-div42').show();
        } else if ($('#select option:selected').text() !== "Other") {
            $('.form-div42').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4EmE5/2/

Hope you can help

Comment: The code gets cut of because your br and input tags aren't closed. you should use `<br />` and `<input />`

Answer (score 3):

Reposting  as per Master **@Kevin Bowersox** supporting comment

Do following changes to your code,

HTML,

```
<div class="form-div1">
    <label>Select your profile</label>
    <br />
    <select id='user'>
        <option value="option1">I'm a first-time user</option>
        <option value="option2">I would like to renew or upgrade</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-div2">
    <label>SEN</label>
    <br />
    <input type "text" name="input1" class="input1" />
</div>
<div class="form-div3">
    <label>Email Address</label>
    <br>
    <input type "text" name="input2" class="input2">
</div>
<div class="form-div4">
    <label>Select your product</label>
    <br>
    <select id='product'>
        <option value="option1">Product1</option>
        <option value="option2">Other</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-div42">
    <label>Specify your product</label>
    <br>
    <input type "text" name="input2" class="input2">
</div>
<div class="form-div5">
    <label>Select your license</label>
    <br />
    <select>
        <option value="option1">25 users</option>
        <option value="option2">50 users</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.form-div2, .form-div3, .form-div4, .form-div5').show();
$('.form-div42').hide();

$('#user').change(function () {
    var selected = $('#user option:selected').text();
    $('.form-div2, .form-div3').toggle(selected == "I'm a first-time user");
});

$('#product').change(function () {
    var selected = $('#product option:selected').text();
    $('.form-div42').toggle(selected == "Other");

});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4EmE5/11/)

Answer (score 1):

The markup should be changed to add `id` attributes to each `select` element you would like to attach an event to.  This allows the code to discern which `select` the appropriate event handler should be attached to.

I have introduced several improvements to the script.  For instance, instead of comparing the text of the selected option, simply retrieve the value of the `select` and compare it to the appropriate value associated with the text.  Also, since these elements are simply in an show/hide state you can pass a boolean expression to `toggle` to conditionally toggle the visibility of the corresponding elements.  Notice the selector can select multiple elements by providing a comma separated list of selectors.

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.form-div2, .form-div3, .form-div4, .form-div5').show();
    $('.form-div42').hide();

    $('#user-type').change(function () {
        $('.form-div2, .form-div3').toggle($(this).val() == "option1");
    });

    $('#product').change(function () {
        $('.form-div42').toggle($(this).val() == "option2");
    });
});
```

**HTML Changes**

```
    <select id="user-type">
        <option value="option1">I'm a first-time user</option>
        <option value="option2">I would like to renew or upgrade</option>
    </select>

    <select id="product">
        <option value="option1">Product1</option>
        <option value="option2">Other</option>
    </select>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/4EmE5/9/

Comment: @Pilot Thanks for letting me know that.  I had the OP's version open for reference and I must have copied that link.

Comment: yours is more cleaner so deleting mine

Comment: @Pilot Appreciate the compliment, but you didn't need to delete yours.  Leave it up there, maybe somebody will tear it apart and you will learn something new.  Or maybe you will get some more rep out of the deal.  Though sometimes harsh, constructive criticism is the most valuable part of SO.  Had you not "critiqued" my answer it would still have the wrong fiddle.  So you made it better.  And I'm sure somebody out there could tear my answer to shreds!

Comment: thanks Master..You are the one who teach us many things..Really appreciated and much supportive

Comment: @KevinBowersox thanks kevin ...You are so supportive...+1 ..I wish I could offer you more than this